# Problema para imprimir na tela uma string com acento

Tags: c, string

Eu gostaria de uma ajuda, pois quando o usuário digita o seu nome com acento, na hora de imprimir na tela o nome, aparece desconfigurado.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <locale.h>        
    int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    char nome[50];

    printf("Olá, seja bem-vindo ao Colega de Quarto, como você se chama ?");
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    fgets(nome,50,stdin);
    printf("\n");
    printf("O que você deseja, %s ?\n\n", nome);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Qual o encoding em que o arquivo foi criado e está a ser editado ?

Answer (score 1):

setlocale (LC_ALL,"portuguese");

adiciona essa linha no começo do main e me diga se deu certo

Comment: Opa, eu esqueci de escrever na publicação, irei editar. Mas mesmo com o setlocale tá dando esse problema. Não faço ideia do que possa ser.

Comment: acabei de testar o código creio que o problema não seja nele, pois os acentos apareceram aqui.

Comment: testa ele aqui e vai ver que não tem problema https://repl.it/languages/c

Comment: está usando qual compilador?

Comment: Estou usaando Code blocks, o problema será o compilador talvez ?

Comment: Provavelmente, alguma configuração errada as vezes, usa o dev c++ se vc tiver iniciando em prog, mas se quiser se aventurar por compiladores mais fortes, procura o vs code ou o atom.

Comment: Troquei pro Dev mesmo e deu certo

Answer (score 1):

Tente substituir seu setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese"); por

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
```

Comment: Também tentei isso e não deu certo, tô pensando que o erro seja no compilador .

Comment: eu usei o dev c++ pra fazer os teste e funcionou normalmente, tente mudar de compilador pra ver se funciona

Comment: Testei aqui e deu certo, é o compilador mesmo.